# list all files in a dir that includes image sequences?

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains several files with different formats (.mpg, .jpg, .mov etc), in addition to several image sequences.

I also have a code that takes an image sequence like:

```
img.000000.jpg
img.000001.jpg
img.000002.jpg
...
```

And turns it into:

```
img.%06d.jpg
```

Is there a way to list all of my image sequences and other files in a given folder? (no sub-folders)

Thanks!

**EDIT**

If i have 5 different .jpg sequences in my folder, i want to have them in 5 separate lists.. not have just one list that contains all of the .jpg files in the folder.

Sample input:

```
file1.log
file2.001.jpg
file2.002.jpg
file2.003.jpg
movie.avi
photo.png
seq.001.jpg
seq.002.jpg
seq.003.jpg
```

Output:

```
file1.log
file2.%03d.jpg
movie.avi
photo.png
seq.%03d.jpg
```

Comment: check python  glob

Comment: link to [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all files in directory with extension .txt in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Comment: It's not a duplicate since i'm trying to "merge" image sequences into one filename, not just list all of the images they contain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python `glob`

```
glob.glob("img*.jpg")
```

> **glob**
>   Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which must be a string containing a path specification. pathname can be either absolute (like /usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile) or relative (like ../../Tools/*/*.gif), and can contain shell-style wildcards. Broken symlinks are included in the results (as in the shell).

Comment: But how would it return each image sequence as one file? For example, let's say i have 2 .jpg image sequences, would it return them as 2 separate file names?

Comment: it would return a list, for example: `["img.000001.jpg", "img.000002.jpg" ]`

Comment: But what if i have 2 .jpg sequences? i don't want them in the same list..

Comment: you can iterate the list and do what ever you want.

Comment: I know, but that would require me to compare each file name to the one that's followed. i was wondering if maybe there was an easier way.

Comment: why not put an sample input and output in your question, then we can understand the question better

Comment: just added it to my post

Comment: Anyways i think i'm just gonna iterate through the list but thanks for your answer!